# jQuery parents selector - traversing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array that inserts articles. When I click the h3 (which has the title) I want to display more information based on the article's index.
I think I need to go up to the `<section id="main">` to find the index of the `<article>` I clicked on starting from my `<h3>`.

Here's my HTML:

```
    <section id="main" class="container">
      <article class="article">
        <section class="featuredImage">
          <img src="images/article_placeholder_1.jpg" alt="" />
        </section>
        <section class="articleContent">
            <a href="#"><h3>Test article title</h3></a>
            <h6>Lifestyle</h6>
        </section>
        <section class="impressions">
          526
        </section>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </article>
    </section>
```

Here is my attempt of getting the index:

```
$('.articleContent a').on('click', function(e) {
    var $target,
        $parent,
        $index;
    e.preventDefault();

    $target = $(e.target);
    $parent = $target.parents('.main');
    $index = $parent.find('.article').index();
    console.log($index);
});
```

Comment: Unless an element can have multiple parents that match the selector, and you need to get all of them, use `.closest()` instead of `.parents()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML nesting structure is the following

```
section#main > article.article > section.articleContent > a
```

You have to search ascendants for more than one level up, so *parent()* is not enough.

*parents()* on the other side can travel for more than one parent and by passing a selector, you can filter the parents.

```
$('.articleContent a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var index = $(this).parents('.article').first().index();
    console.log(index);
});
```

So this will find the first element with the class "article".
Notice you could also be more specific, by using the selector *"article.article"*

Comment: Or start using data-id="theValue", to handle it, $('.articleContent a').on('click', function() { console.log($(this).data('id'))})

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Did a enter, so it became posted. You are fast, dont know what script you are running, but you are fast.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan ok I'll add some info.

Comment: @Grumpy I don't understand your comment

Comment: @TonySamperi, you could add the property data-article-id="value" to your h3 element and read the value when you click the h3 element like, $('.articleContent a').on('click', function() { console.log($(this).data('articleId'))})

Comment: @Grumpy I don't see why adding an attribute, if counting is enough.